# What is MSO.dll

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, office365

While browsing the internet using Chrome, sometimes my computer becomes sluggish, this often happens while playing video. When I open Resource Monitor (Windows 7) it shows a file from Microsoft Office (MSO.DLL) being accessed heavily by Chrome. I have previously disabled all of my chrome extensions and that did not solve it, and have not reenabled any Office-related extensions.

[image: High disk usage caused by MSO.DLL]

I couldn't find any other problems like this via a Google search, so I'm not sure how to proceed. At the very least I would like to know what purpose the file serves so I can at least feel better about my disk being thrashed.

Comment: Do you know it's an authentic file?  Seems weird to me chromed calling that if all extensions are disabled.  You might try uploading the MSO.dll file to https://www.virustotal.com/

Comment: I sent it through, and all the scanners said it was not a virus.

Answer (score 0):

the latest versions of Office deploy add-ins for FireFox and Chrome if they are detected.  They are mostly used for interactions with Lync and SharePoint or Office365 is you have a subscriptions.

Re-run the Office Setup - and uninstall the Chrome add-in and see if you still have this issue.